# upload custom product image programatically

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload

**Question** : Once Registered user upload **custom image** [custom image is Image which is uploaded by User ] in [product view page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html) & click on button "**Save design**" , we are **creating Product Programatically**  . **We want to upload that custom image to newly created product programatically.**

Now we are using below code to upload **existing image** [ already saved image in server ] programatically.

```
protected function _createProduct($type, $doSave=true, $originalProduct) 
    {

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

        // finally set custom data
        $product->setName($originalProduct->getName()); 

        // add product images

        $images = array(
            'thumbnail'   => 'image.png',
            'small_image' => 'image.png',
            'image'       => 'image.png',
        ); 

        $dir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'example/amasty/';

        foreach ($images as $imageType => $imageFileName) {
            $path = $dir . $imageFileName;
            if (file_exists($path)) {
                try {
                    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($path, $imageType, false);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
            } else {
                echo "Can not find image by path: `{$path}`<br/>";
            }
        }

        if ($doSave)
            $product->save();
        // To save inside my_designs

        $data = array('title'=>fav1_id,'product_id'=>$product->getId(),'customer_id'=> $customerId, 'value'=>image);
        $model = Mage::getModel('example/mydesign')->setData($data);
      try 
         {
        $fav1_id = $model->save()->getId();
        echo "Custom Design saved successfully";
          } catch (Exception $e)
          {
            echo $e->getMessage();   
          }
        // To save inside my_designs end

        return $product;
    }
```

**Sidenote** : Once Registered user upload **custom image** in [product view page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html)  & click on **Add to cart**, we are saving Custom image  in Server in path : `media/custom_options/quote` and displaying image path in Table : `sales_flat_quote_item_options`

Comment: Sorry I'm working on Magento 2

Comment: The code you provided does not include code to upload for, I think it's just to add button.

Comment: @NehaRaval code in question will create product programtically & upload image which is already present in server. but i need to upload custom image to the programtically created product.

Comment: @NehaRaval please check `edit` part in question......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think error in below line

instead of

```
  $dir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'example/amasty/';
```

Try below on

```
  $dir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'custom_options/quote/';
```

Comment: Hi plz come here once bro http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55514/teja-bhagavan

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara I dont have rights to message in that chatroom

Comment: check once now.

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Thanks,  after click on `save design` i need to upload custom image to the `programtically created product`, for that i need to `save custom image in server` , but once i click on `save design` custom image is not saving in server.

Comment: please check `edit` part in question......